3 way switch, possible compatibility issue?
I’ve been remodeling houses for 20+ years and have never seen the issue I’m having before ,if a dimmer wasn’t in the circuit.
Replacing switches to new style (not “smart” rocker switches.  Replaced both as previously wired, no dice. Disassembled,
Identified & marked line and load.  Reassembled using different new (3way) switches.  Again, not proper operation on both sides.
Re installed old switches, using same line/ load wires.  Works perfectly as before I started. Put 1 new switch in, again not proper operation.  Reinstalled old switches, works fine.
I can diagram a 3 way switch circuit regardless of where power is or whether it’s a switched half of an outlet or what have you.  This should have been completely straightforward, but…
I have no idea why there would be a compatibility issue, but???
Any ideas ?

3-way switches are not line and load. They are common and 2 travelers. Location (top vs bottom, left vs. right) of screws for common vs. travelers varies by brand/model. What is usually the case is that common is one color screw (typically black) and travelers are a different color screw (typically brass). So the key is usually to match "common to common" and "travelers to travelers" - which may be a different physical configuration (top/bottom, left/right) than the old switches.

Didja read the instructions?

Can you elaborate on what you classify as "not proper operation on both sides"?
